# How to use netcat as compressing proxy

Tags: bash, networking, proxy, netcat

I have a server that receives messages in a text-based protocol. The server doesn't send back anything. These messages eat up network bandwidth a lot since the protocol is not binary and doesn't have any compression. To fix this I want to run a compressing proxy on the client and on the server side. On the client side, the proxy should receive the data over TCP, compress it, and send to the server-side proxy. The server-side proxy should receive data, decompress it, and send to the server application.

The client-side code should be something like this:

```
cd /tmp
mknod backpipe p
nc localhost 7171 0<backpipe | gzip | nc server-ip 7272 | tee backpipe
```

And on the server side:

```
cd /tmp
mknod backpipe p
nc -l -p 7272 0<backpipe | gunzip | nc -l -p 7171 | tee backpipe
```

The server application works on 7171 port and the compressing proxy uses the 7272 port to transfer data. But this is not working for me for some reason.

Comment: netcat is not really a programming language or a programming tool. You would probably get better answers on other StackExchange sites like SuperUser or ServerFault, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost got there.

client side, listen on local port 7171, forward to remote server at server-ip:7272:

```
mkfifo client_rely
nc -l 7171 < client_rely | gzip -c | nc server-ip 7272 > client_rely
```

server side, listen on port 7272, forward to real server on port 7171:

```
mkfifo server_rely
nc -l 7272 < server_rely | gzip -d -c | nc 7171 > server_rely
```

note that this example uses `nc` shipped with macOS.